# How to find next similar sibling moving down in the dom tree

Tags: jquery

What I need over here is while positioned on one of the `dt` elements I want to jump to the next `dt` element. How can I achieve this?

```
<dl class="accordion">
    <dt>Select Category</dt>
    <dd></dd>

    <dt>select product</dt>
    <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

```js
(function($) {
    var allPanels = $('.accordion > dd').hide();
    $('.accordion > dd:first-of-type').show();
    $('.accordion > dt:first-of-type').addClass('accordion-active');

    jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
        $this = $(this);
        $target = $this.next(); 
        if (!$this.hasClass('accordion-active')) {
            $this.parent().children('dd').slideUp();
            jQuery('.accordion > dt').removeClass('accordion-active');
            $this.addClass('accordion-active');
            $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
        }    
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: it doesnt work ...$this.next("dt") points to same element which is clicked somehow...i want the next dt element in the dom

Comment: `$target = $this.nextAll('dt').eq(0);`?!

Comment: thats awesome...did the trick...u can post an answer for it

Comment: @payalarora freedomn-m made a better answer than i could :)

Comment: thanks guys...i was an important thing...i saw everywhere but cudnt find it....thanks a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What appears to be the obvious option in jquery: `.next("dt")` is not, because `.next()` always only returns the very next sibling, applying a filter `.next(filter)` still only returns the very next sibling, but only if it matches the filter

jQuery provides two alternatives: [.nextUntil()](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [.nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

These can be used as:

```
nextdt = thisdt.nextUntil("dt").next();
nextdt = thisdt.nextAll("dt").first();
```

where nextUntil gets the next siblings until the match (so you then need another next()) and nextAll gets all the matching (so you then need first()).

In the question's code, this gives the following update:

```
jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $target = $this.nextAll("dt").first();
```

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wk1mkeq/

Comment: +1 You're right, that isn't obvious.  If I had to guess without your explanation, my guess would be that `next('filter')` returns the next element matching the filter, and it would have been wrong.  A useful clarification.