# Get next li after element and get input value in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found input value in element such as:

```
alert($(ui.item).find('input').val());
```

How can I get next li element after ui.item and find input value for it?

I tried it:

```
 alert($(ui.item).next("li").find('input').val());
```

Html part:

```
<ul id="sortable" class="ui-sortable" style="list-style-type: none;">
 <li class="ui-sortable-handle" style="">
  <div id="row_attr_118_8">
   <input id="attr_118_8" class="input sortInp" name="attr_118_8" value="741" 
 type="text">
   </div>
 </li>
 <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
  <div id="row_attr_40_8">
   <input id="attr_40_8" class="input sortInp" name="attr_40_8" value="188" type="text">
  </div>
 </li>
 <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
 <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post html part?

Comment: `$(ui.item).nextAll("li").first().find('input').val()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find next similar sibling moving down in the dom tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562192/how-to-find-next-similar-sibling-moving-down-in-the-dom-tree)

Comment: I get undefined in my alert

Comment: I added html part

Comment: What's "ui.item" ?

Comment: @freedomn-m it is part of `ui` object accessible in jQuery-UI events

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this:

```
var value = $(".ui-sortable").children("li").eq(0).find('input').val();
```

This selects the first *li*, but you can change the index in the *eq* to select the item you want

Comment: Which is the same as: `$(".ui-sortable input:first")`

Comment: Yes, but my code is to show him how to navigate the DOM and get to the element he wants, and also get other inputs rather than the first. Of course your selector does the job.

Comment: I'm still guessing what `ui.item` is :)

Comment: ahahahahha who knows!! :D

Comment: You are irrelevant, the answer fits the code the user provided. I assumed the `ui.item` was a typo.