# hover over one div to show the nearest div of a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to hover over one div and use jquery to find the nearest div by the name and to show that div.

```
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="somethingelse"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

all the .footer classes will be hidden but i want to make it so that when i over over the .body class, only the nearest .footer class shows. [ meaning : if i hover over the first .body class, only the first .footer will be shown. ]

my current code isn't working and i'm starting to wonder if it's something wrong with it.

current jquery code :

```
$('.footer').hide();
$('.body').hover(function(){
     $(this).closest('.footer').find('.footer').show();
});
```

Comment: `$(this).nextAll(".footer").first()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find next similar sibling moving down in the dom tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562192/how-to-find-next-similar-sibling-moving-down-in-the-dom-tree)

Comment: `.closest()` *traverses **up** through its ancestors in the DOM tree* (see: https://api.jquery.com/closest/). So this would only behave as intended if `.footer` appeared *before* `.body`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the problem is the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562192/how-to-find-next-similar-sibling-moving-down-in-the-dom-tree/38562633#38562633), the reason is slightly different.

When you use `.closest(".class")` it's the equivalent of `.parents().filter(".class").first()` (or `.last()`, I don't recall exactly which way `parents()` works as that's what `closest` is for).

ie it goes up the tree

So `$(".body").closest(".entry")` would give you an element for your HTML.

In this case, you want siblings, but more specifically the next one.  There's a jquery method `.next()` which looks like it's correct, but as detailed in the link above, this only gives the very next one (in your HTML this would be the `date` div) even if a filter is applied - so `$(this).next(".footer")` would give an empty set (as it's not `.date`).

The work around is:

```
$(this).nextAll(".footer").first()
```

Once you get this working, your will find that your hover does not work as expected as the footers are not hiding again - as you're using `.hover` rather than `mouseenter` `mouseout`, you just need to move the `.hide()` call inside the *second* event handler, giving:

```js
// startup
$(".footer").hide();

// event
$(".body").hover(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".footer").first().show();
}, function() {
    $(".footer").hide();
});
```

```css
div > div { width: 100px; height: 10px }
.body { border: 1px solid red; }
.date { border: 1px solid blue; }
.footer { border: 1px solid green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="somethingelse"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't give you the nearest `.footer`, it gives you the nearest **NEXT** `.footer`, which is likely what the OP want according to the HTML example. But if the OP strictly wanted the nearest `.footer` as stated in the question, then this solution is no good.

Comment: @RacilHilan indeed, but I'm not sure what circumstance you would want the 'footer' *above* the current item.  Given *any* div (eg "closest" with class "a") then there's potential for a different question.   Given "body" and "footer", it would be strange to not have it the next.  The example provided in the question does not clarify and this should be raised as a question on the OP.

Comment: Agreed. That's what I said, and you just clarified it with details :). I also agree that it should be a question to the OP, but there are already good answers for the **next** requirement, and I posted an answer for the **nearest** requirement, so there is no longer a need for the question as the OP can choose (likely your answer). I just wanted to leave a comment, more for the future readers who may land here by searching for "nearest". I commented on your answer because you were the first ;), and I didn't want to spam all answers with the same comment.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me.

I was trying to find the nearest div with specific class to show and hide. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).closest('.footer')
```

You should start to use console.log() sometimes to check elements you would like to get. This does not find anything so nothing further to search and to show.

If you possibly can separate bodies and footers into containers you can do smth like
[this](https://jsfiddle.net/zkjrb5np/19/).

Comment: This confirms the issue, but doesn't provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make use of **`nextUntil(".footer").next();`** as below

```js
$('.body').hover(function() {
  $(this).nextUntil(".footer").next().show();
}, function() {
  $(".footer").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.footer {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="somethingelse">somethingelse</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by freedomn-m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48193669/3215948) offered a good explanation and good solution in case you want the nearest **NEXT** `.footer`, which seems to be the case from your example HTML.

However, if you want your request strictly, so you want exact **NEAREST** `.footer`, then his solution will not work for you. And I don't think there is a jQuery built-in functionality that can give you that, so you'll have to do it manually. Get the list of the children of the parent (don't use the siblings as they don't include the current element) and go through the list to calculate the distance from your current element using the indexes and then select the `.footer` that is really the **nearest**.

```js
$('.body').hover(function() {
  var children = $(this).parent().children();
  var index = children.index(this);
  var closest = children.length;
  var footer = -1;
  children.each(function(i, child) {
    if (i !== index && $(child).hasClass("footer")) {
      var distance = Math.abs(index - i);
      if (distance < closest) {
        closest = distance;
        footer = i;
      }
    }
  });
  if (footer > -1)
    children.eq(footer).show();
}, function() {
  $(".footer").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.footer {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="somethingelse">somethingelse</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

If you don't care much about the performance, you can shorten the code a bit by selecting the list of `.footer` instead of the children of the parent, and then let jQuery give you the index of each of them. Not very efficient, but shorter code:

```js
$('.body').hover(function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  var closest = 9999;
  var footer;
  $(this).siblings(".footer").each(function(i, sibling) {
    var distance = Math.abs(index - $(sibling).index());
    if (distance < closest) {
      closest = distance;
      footer = sibling;
    }
  });
  if (footer !== undefined)
    $(footer).show();
}, function() {
  $(".footer").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.footer {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="somethingelse">somethingelse</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Inspired by freedomn-m's comment, we can also use the `.prevAll()` and `.nextAll()` methods to get the previous and next `.footer` siblings. These two methords return the siblings ordered by the closest, so we simply pick the first one of each list, subtract their indexes from our element's index (to find the distance), compare them together, and return the closest. This solution is also less efficient than the first one, but you may find the code easier to read:

```js
$('.body').hover(function() {
  var me = $(this);
  var prev = me.prevAll(".footer").first();
  var next = me.nextAll(".footer").first();

  if (prev.length == 0)
    next.show();
  else if (next.length == 0)
    prev.show();
  else {
    index = me.index();
    if (Math.abs(prev.index() - index) < Math.abs(next.index() - index))
      prev.show();
    else
      next.show();
  }
}, function() {
  $(".footer").hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

.footer {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="date">date</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>

  <div class="body">body</div>
  <div class="somethingelse">somethingelse</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this scenario, it should be possible to use `.nextUntil(".footer").length` and `.prevUntil(".footer").length` - I had a quick go, but it does some unhelpful things - eg if the next item is the one you're looking for, you get an empty set so `.next()` on that gives nothing and it makes it difficult to tell if it's zero before there aren't any or zero because it's next.  So you end up with some nasty looking code.

Comment: @freedomn-m :))))))... I've read your comment 3 times and cannot stop laughing. You're good at explaining things. Yes, it's a cool idea to use `.nextUntil` and `.prevUntil`, but like you said, they won't work, because they don't include the selector. However, you can use `.nextAll` and `.prevAll` instead. I've added them as a third solution, thanks to you ;).

Answer (score 0):

**IF** your html is gonna keep those triads layout, you don't need jQuery for it. 
Just use CSS to select the second div after the .body on hover

```css
div{width:100px; height:100px; background-color:lime; margin:10px; float:left}

.body{background:yellow; clear:left;}
.footer{display:none;}

.body:hover + div + div{
  display:block;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="date"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="somethingelse"></div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
```