# Add class to next element with attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a list of sections. Some of them have a special attribute to identify them.
By scroll I add a class to a section with the attribute, as soon as it is in the viewport. This works without problems.

But I also want to add a class "next" to the next section with this attribute.

I already tried `.next()`, but this is not working. And `.nextAll()` is adding the class to all sections with this attribute.

**HTML**

```
<section></section>
<section scrollsec="yes"></section>
<div></div>
<section></section>
<section scrollsec="yes"></section>
<section></section>
<div></div>
<section></section>
<section scrollsec="yes"></section>
```

**JS**

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $(window).height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}

$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('section[scrollsec=yes]').each(function () {
        if (isScrolledIntoView(this) === true) {
            $(this).addClass('visible');
            $(this).next("section[scrollsec=yes]").addClass('next');
        } else {
          $(this).removeClass('visible');
        }
    });

});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybqjc3uf/1/)

Comment: It's not intuitive.  `.next()` gets the next item then checks if it matches the filter - you need `.nextAll(filter).first()`.  There are many duplicate questions on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find next similar sibling moving down in the dom tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562192/how-to-find-next-similar-sibling-moving-down-in-the-dom-tree)

Comment: maybe I just searched for the wrong terms... I will check thank you

Comment: To start with, you should not use invalid HTML5 attributes. Use `data-*` attributes instead.