# Focus onto next input on Enter key using jQuery script

Tags: html, jquery, forms

I'm using this jQuery script to focus onto next input when enter pressed:

```
  $(function() {
    $(".form >input").on('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        $(this).next('input').focus();
      }
    });
  });
```

It does work with this basic skinny HTML form

```
<div class="form">
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

But not with this one

```
<div class="form">
    <input name="cislo1" type="text" class=cislo1 placeholder="" id="cislo1" autofocus /><br>
    <input name="cislo2" type="text" class=cislo2 placeholder="" id="cislo2" /><br>
    <input name="cislo3" type="text" class=cislo3 placeholder="" id="cislo3" /><br>
    <input name="cislo4" type="text" class=cislo4 placeholder="" id="cislo4" /><br>
    <input name="cislo5" type="text" class=cislo5 placeholder="" id="cislo5"  /><br>
    <input name="cislo6" type="text" class=cislo6 placeholder="" id="cislo6" /><br>
    <input name="cislo7" type="text" class=cislo7 placeholder="" id="cislo7" /><br>
    <input name="cislo8" type="text" class=cislo8 placeholder="" id="cislo8" /><br>
    <input name="cislo9" type="text" class=cislo9 placeholder="" id="cislo9" /><br>
    <input name="cislo10" type="text" class=cislo10 placeholder="" id="cislo10" /><br>
    <input name="cislo11" type="text" class=cislo11 placeholder="" id="cislo11" /><br>
</div>
```

What seems to be the problem here? Help me please, I'm stuck

Comment: `$(".form >input")` - you have a big fat `p` in between `.form` and `input` in the second case.  So would need to be `$(".form input") or `$(".form > p > input")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find next similar sibling moving down in the dom tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562192/how-to-find-next-similar-sibling-moving-down-in-the-dom-tree)

Comment: (question isn't the same, but the answer is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is you are using direct child selector like:

```
$(".form > input")
```

This only matches any direct `input` element inside `form` class, but in your next example `input` is not the direct child. So, you need to descent sector instead like:

```
$(".form input")
```

This will match any `input` inside the `form` class where it is a direct child or not.

Also, you need to replace

```
$(this).next('input').focus();
```

with this:

```
$(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
```

This is needed because `.next()` will get the immediately following sibling of each element, but here `input` is not the immediate sibling. We also have some `<br>` in between which are causing the issue. This can be resolved using `.nextAll('input:first')` instead.

**Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".form input").on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      $(this).nextAll('input:first').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form">

  <p class="cislo">
    <input name="cislo1" type="text" class=cislo1 placeholder="" id="cislo1" autofocus onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo1.value=cislo1.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
    <input name="cislo2" type="text" class=cislo2 placeholder="" id="cislo2" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo2.value=cislo2.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
    <input name="cislo3" type="text" class=cislo3 placeholder="" id="cislo3" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo3.value=cislo3.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
    <input name="cislo4" type="text" class=cislo4 placeholder="" id="cislo4" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" oninput="cislo4.value=cislo4.value.slice(0,2)" /><br>
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: Found the issue. Updated the demo also.

Comment: Didn't see those naughty `<br/>`s hidng at the end.  `.next()` gets the next, *then* filters to the selector.