# Override Bootstrap Label

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to figure out how to override the default bootstrap code. I would a working snippet which enables floating label. However, the label is targeted in Jquery and css but bootstrap is using it's default label. I even tried giving the label an ID or class but it still will not work.

```
 <div class="row p-5">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <label class="label-test-new">Floating label</label>
                        <select id="select" class="js-select" multiple>
                            <option>Sed pulvinar erat efficitur turpis dapibus mattis.</option>
                            <option>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</option>
                            <option>Nam vitae ipsum rutrum, posuere lorem non, aliquet libero.</option>
                            <option>In faucibus lorem sed sem maximus ultricies.</option>
                            <option>Vestibulum pellentesque dui sed quam vulputate volutpat.</option>
                            <option>Nunc cursus massa non augue ultrices, in placerat massa ultrices.</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>


.label-test-new {
    &.selected {
        top: -20px;
        font-size: 12px;
        transform: translateY(0);
    }
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #C2185B;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 25px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

$('.js-select').select2().on('select2:open', (elm) => {
  const targetLabel = $(elm.target).prev('label');
  targetLabel.addClass('selected');
}).on('select2:close', (elm) => {
  const target = $(elm.target);
  const targetLabel = target.prev('label');
  const targetOptions = $(elm.target.selectedOptions);
  if (targetOptions.length === 0) {
    targetLabel.removeAttr('class');
  }
});
```

Also how do you target a apply it to this kind of label:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Request.RTMFlag, new { @class = "header-label" })
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking or what you've tried, but if it helps, your `@Html.LabelFor' creates html `<label for="Request_RTMFlag" class='header-label'>[DisplayName of RTMFlag property]</label>` - so you can target `label` or `label.header-label` or `label[for=Request_RTMFlag]` or `$(elm.target).prevAll('label').first()`

Comment: Note that `.prev(selector)` doesn't do what it looks like it should do (I see this a lot here) - it does `.prev().filter(selector)` - *not* `.prevAll().filter(selector).first()` - ie it gets the previous element and then returns it if it matches the selector - it doesn't "find" the previous item that matches.  In your case that's relevant as `elm.target` will be the `select2` control which is inserted *after* the `select` - so `$(elm.target).prev()` will be the `select` so will *never* be the `label`.  More info (prev/next work the same) https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562633/2181514

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try it out as soon as I can find a way to override the default bootstrap label that's affecting my own css label changes. lol

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important` to override

or inline css using property `style`

or in your css using `div > div > label`

You might need to set !important on the 2 other technic.