# How to call specific elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am currently working on creating a multiple choice test.

Beneath the selection buttons, I have added an "explanation" section with the class "exp", I am trying to make the class hidden, and become visible when the corresponding question is clicked, by using HTML class calls. There is a paragraph closer than the paragraph element containing the explanation, so I am unsure how to call this paragraph.

Can anyone help to explain why the class does not become visible with the current code?

```js
var fatiguescore = 0
$(".exp").addClass("novisibly")

$('.q').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(".correct"))
    $(this).addClass("theright") && ++fatiguescore;
  else {
    $(this).addClass("thewrong");
  }
  $(this).closest("table").find(".q").attr('disabled', 'disabled') && sessionStorage.setItem("fatigueScore", fatiguescore) && $(this).closest("p" [Explanation]).find(".exp").removeClass("novisibly");
})
```

```css
.novisibly {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<p>Example question?</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q correct" type="button">Option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">Option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q type="button">Option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">Option 4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<p class="exp">Explanation:</p>
<br>
<br>

<h3>Question 2</h3>
<p>Example question 2?</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q type="button">option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q correct" type="button">option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">option 4n</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<p class="exp">Explanation:</p>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: What is `.closest("p" [Explanation])` supposed to do? Why do you search the closest `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `.closest` find the closest *parent* and `<p>` is not a parent of the button.

As `this` is the button that was clicked and it's inside a table, you can go up to the table using `.closest` (closest parent, not closest sibling/element) then use `.nextAll(..).first()`

```
$(this).closest("table").nextAll(".exp").first()
```

```js
var fatiguescore = 0
$(".exp").addClass("novisibly")

$('.q').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(".correct")) {
    $(this).addClass("theright");
    ++fatiguescore;
  }
  else {
    $(this).addClass("thewrong");
  }
  $(this).closest("table").find(".q").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  //sessionStorage.setItem("fatigueScore", fatiguescore);
  $(this).closest("table").nextAll(".exp").first().removeClass("novisibly");
})
```

```css
.novisibly {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<p>Example question?</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q correct" type="button">Option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">Option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q type="button">Option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">Option 4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<p class="exp">Explanation:</p>
<br>
<br>

<h3>Question 2</h3>
<p>Example question 2?</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button class=q type="button">option 1</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">option 2</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="q correct" type="button">option 3</button></td>
    <td><button class=q type="button">option 4n</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>
<p class="exp">Explanation:</p>
<br>
<br>
```

---

As a recommendation, I would group each question in it's own div/wrapper, this can make things slightly easier, eg:

```
<div class='question'>
  <h3>Question 1</h3> 
  <p>Question</p>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
  <div class='exp'>Explanation</div>
</div>
```

This will also allow you to style the questions, eg put a box around each question+button+exp.   But will also allow you to remove the unfriendly `.nextAll(..).first()`, eg:

```
$(this).closest(".question").find(".exp").slideDown();
```

You can also use styling rather than `<br/>` to add spacing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `($(this).hasClass(".correct"))` or use `.next()` for next element

Comment: `$(this).next()` would not give anything as each button is an only-child.   `$(this).closest("table").next()` would not give the exp and there's a `br` in the way, and also `$(this).closest("table").next(".exp")` as `.exp` is not the next element.  [See here for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562633/2181514).

Comment: Thanks, @freedomn-m, I appreciate this.