# How to remove class except from clicked group with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML code like this, Now I want to add/remove the class for `content` div on click `icon` by using jQuery. Also I want to remove all instances of the `active` class except the clicked one. Thank you.

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <p class="icon"></p>
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <p class="icon"></p>
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <p class="icon"></p>
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

My jQuery

```
$(".icon").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".content").toggleClass("active");
    $(this).next(":not(.content)").removeClass("active");
});
```

Comment: "*Also I want to remove the class*" - which class?  content?  or icon?

Comment: class named "active"

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38562633/2181514) regarding `.next(filter)` - you *possibly* need to use `.nextAll(".content")`

Comment: *class named "active"* - wow, there's no mention of "active" anywhere in your question except the code.  Maybe you could clarify that via an [edit]?  Which element(s) have "active"?  `.content`?

Comment: Given your html `$(this).next(":not(.content)")` will always be 0 elements.   I would guess from your description that you want to put `$(".active").removeClass("active")` as the first line (in the event handler) and remove the `:not...` line.

Comment: Both tenets of your question have been covered a great many times on SO. Please search before posting. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$(".icon").click(function() {
  var _content = $(this).next(".content");
  $(".content").not(_content).removeClass("active")
  _content.toggleClass("active");
});
```

This will remove the active class from all other .content than the one in relation to the click icon.

And then it will toggle the click on the clicked content.

**Demo**

```js
$(".icon").click(function() {
  var _content = $(this).next(".content");
  $(".content").not(_content).removeClass("active")
  _content.toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="icon">icon</p>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="icon">icon</p>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="icon">icon</p>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: active class is removed on next click on the same icon class

Comment: @JunaidShaikh hard to tell exactly what OP wants as they state *I want to add/remove the class for content div on click* ... add/*remove*  (but they also still don't state which class (the active class))

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.siblings('.content')` to find the content div next to icon

```
 $(".icon").click(function() {
      $('.content').removeClass('active');
      $(this).siblings('.content').addClass('active');
 });
```

---

Working Code below

```js
$(".icon").click(function() {
  $('.content').removeClass('active');
  $(this).siblings('.content').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <p class="icon">a</p>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="icon">b</p>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p class="icon">c</p>
    <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rejig your HTML slightly:

```
<ul id="myListName">
 <li>
  <p class="icon"></p>
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <p class="icon"></p>
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
 </li>
 <li>
  <p class="icon"></p>
  <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Then you can simply do this:

```
$('#myListName .icon').click(function () {
    $('#myListName .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).sibling('.content').toggleClass('active');
    
});
```

Which would remove the active class from any element within that list, before adding it to any sibling element that has the content class.

Comment: The ID isn't necessary _or_ advisable. It prevents reuse of the function.

Comment: It seems your answer is to add an `id=` - yet the code would work the same without the id

Comment: `$(this).closest('.content')` - check the HTML layout.   .content is not a *parent* of .icon

Comment: I'm fairly sure they'd want to limit the scope of the function to one particular list - `content` is a pretty generic classname

Comment: @freedomn-m - I genuinely thought closest worked for siblings/descendants as well as ancestors. My bad